# How to properly seed a mersenne twister RNG?

Tags: c, random, mersenne-twister

This is actually not as simple as I first thought.

In the absence of a hardware RNG, what is the best way to seed a Mersenne Twister?

Or should I say, what is an acceptable way to seed a a Mersenne Twister RNG that is used to generate UUID's?

Comment: google offers http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/networking/puis/ch23_08.htm

Comment: There is a nice discussion of pseudo-random number generators [here](http://www.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/d.jones/GoodPracticeRNG.pdf) including a section on proper seed of PRNGs (see rule 3), which uses `md5sum` and `/dev/random` to generate seeds. (This also includes a number of PRNG alogrithms which are a lot easier to code up than the MT but are arguably just as good).

Comment: @Chris do you want to post that as an answer?  I think it's a very good article and is helpful for seeding PRNG in general.

Comment: @MattH Added my comment as an answer and elaborated a bit. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a nice discussion of pseudo-random number generators [here](http://www.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/d.jones/GoodPracticeRNG.pdf) including a section on the proper seeding of PRNGs (see rule 3), which uses `md5sum` and `/dev/random` or `/dev/urandom` to generate seeds.

This also includes a number of PRNG alogrithms which are a lot easier to code up (< 10 lines of code) than the MT but are arguably just as good (long periods and pass all of the Dieharder tests for randomness).

Further Reading:

1. [Seed std::mt19937 from std::random_device](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/109260/seed-stdmt19937-from-stdrandom-device)
2. [Best way to seed mt19937_64 for Monte Carlo simulations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24334012/best-way-to-seed-mt19937-64-for-monte-carlo-simulations)
3. [How to obtain (almost) unique system identifier in a cross platform way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16858782/how-to-obtain-almost-unique-system-identifier-in-a-cross-platform-way)